# GIT variables of version?

Tags: git, svn

I would like to use variables of version like svn in git repo.

Example:

```
// Version              :$Revision $
// Url                  :$HeadURL: $
// Updated the :$Date: $
// By                   :$Author:  $
```

Is these supported in GIT?